# Relative paths in Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a .xml.j2 template that I'm populating through ansible.  I have a variable being passed in by ansible that may be a relative or an absolute path. If the path is relative, I need to prepend a parent directory path. Is there a way for jinja2 to check whether a path is relative or absolute, and proceed accordingly? If not, can I do this in ansible and pass in the modified variable?

Answer (score 5):

Ansible gives you the [`realpath` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) (along with some other useful ones for manipulating paths):

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ '.' | realpath }}"
```

---

Answering your later comment:

> Unfortunately, I don't just need the real path. I need "if it's a realpath, great. If it's not, prepend this path to it, which is set in another variable"

You can use a `==` operator to verify if `path` is a relative or an absolute one:

```
path == path | realpath
```

Not to mention something as trivial as checking for `/` at the front.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for inputs like `../../folder`. The docs say "To get the real path of a link", so maybe this is just for symlinks? I would it reasonable to have something more general.